# Zimri age at the time of sin?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, age, parashat-balak

What was Zimri's age at the time he had relations with Kozbi?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Since he was Shimon son,he was at least 210 or the Maharsha says 250 years old.

Comment: Where does the Maharsha say this?

Comment: How do we know that he was Shimon's son?

Comment: @Curiouser maybe Maharasha on the Torah.

Comment: The pasuk says his name is Zimri ben Salu. -1

Comment: @DoubleAA: Sanhedrin 82b identifies him with "Shaul the son of the Canaanite woman" mentioned in Gen. 46:10 among the sons of Shimon. The Maharsha that SimchasTorah referenced is [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37969&pgnum=330), in his comments on that Gemara.

Comment: @Alex I wonder though if that is meant to be pshat, or an explanation for why the Tribe of Shimon did poorly (because they had Cananite blood). Additionally, this post is clearly a riddle. Finally, he should have included all that information in this answer.

Comment: @DoubleAA: it's entirely possible that it's not meant as peshat, any more so than the other places where the Gemara or Midrash identifies people with each other (see [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/984/37)). Indeed, Maharsha calls it a דרש. Still, though, he also says that it's not logical that Shimon really would have married a Canaanite woman, when that nation was so detestable to the Avos (see Pesachim 50a, which makes a similar point about Yehudah marrying בת איש כנעני) - which is why the Gemara assumes it to be an epithet for Zimri.

Comment: @DoubleAA: Rashi (Bereshit 46:10) says the Canaanite Woman refers to Dinah: http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8241/showrashi/true#v10

Comment: @Menachem Yes...

Comment: @DoubleAA: my point was that there wasn't any Cananite blood, because Dinah wasn't a Cananite woman.

Comment: @Menachem Those two Midrashim are dealing with the same issue in the text (how Shimon could marry a Cananite), but it seems they come to different conclusions. And even assuming they are meant to be taken in consonance, the pasuk in Bereishit is clearly meant to be derogatory to 'Dinah' for "VaYetzei Dinah", so it could still be an explanation for why Shimon did poorly: they had similar-to-Cananite blood in that Dinah showed Cananite character traits.